# Странный синтаксис С++ кода в библиотеке LuaBind

Tags: c++

Заинтересовался либой [LuaBind](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/luabind/docs.html). Читаю доку, разбираю примеры. И тут попался странный хлоуворлд:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <luabind/luabind.hpp>

void greet()
{
    std::cout << "hello world!\n";
}

extern "C" int init(lua_State* L)
{
    using namespace luabind;

    open(L);

    module(L)                      // Что это за конструкция такая?
    [                              //
        def("greet", &greet)       //
    ];                             //

    return 0;
}
```

Код вроде бы С++, но то, что я выделил комментами ... не пойму. Что это?
Собственно в этом вопрос.

Comment: вполне возможно что функция `module` возвращает массив того типа который возвращает функция `def` - тоесть это скорее всего индекс

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вот, например, набор определений на самом что ни на есть базовом языке С (!), который позволит вам написать ту же самую конструкцию

```
const int L = 42;
void greet(void) {}
int *module(int i) { static int a[1] = { 0 }; return a; }
int def(const char *c, void f(void)) { return 0; }

int main()
{
    module(L)
    [
        def("greet", &greet)
    ];
}
```

Что говорит о том, что данная конструкция использует самый базовый синтаксис языка и ничего необычного в ней нет.

Семантика этой конструкции в Lua будет, конечно, более богатой из-за использования перегруженных операторов, но использованный тут синтаксис - банален.

Comment: Спасибо за пример)

Answer (score 7):

А если бы это выражение было записано так

```
module(L)[def("greet", &greet)];
```

оно стало бы понятнее?

А если так

```
m[x]
```

то есть, выше это просто обращение к элементу некого массива, который возвращает функция `module(...)`. А индекс вычисляется функцией `def(...,...)`.

Но `module()` может возвращать объект, у которого определен оператор `operator[...]`. В таком случае это все будет просто два вызова. И схематически можно описать так (предупреждаю - схематически!)

```
auto tmp = module(L);
tmp.operator[](def("greet", &greet));
```

Comment: Похоже на правду. Надо на тестовом примере проверить. Если честно, с таким не сталкивался и не использовал, естественно, сам.

Comment: Действительно, "разнесенные" квадратные скобки - сбили с толку)

Comment: Majestio кстати, module(L) может быть индексом, а def - массивом, запись через .operator[] не всегда эквивалента, а только если operator[] был перегружен. Можно записать 3[array] и это будет тоже самое, что и array[3], ели перегрузки нет. luabind::module это функция, возвращающая класс с таким оператором

Comment: да, это известный сишный трюк. Но только в примере выше он не приносит нового. А вот operator[] - приносит.

Answer (score 1):

luabind::module это функция, возвращающая класс luabind::module_. У него переопределен оператор [], получающий тип luabind::scope в качестве аргумента. luabind::class_::def, luabind::def возвращают luabind::class_& , который является потомком luabind::scope и преобразуется к нему. В остальном, это всего лишь использование перегруженного оператора[] для передачи класса-функтора классу-исполнителю (модулю).